# Get geolocation via Telegram bot using inline

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

If you use the bot via Inline in the Telegram, the bot can request the user's location, if this is enabled in the bot settings. The [telethon.events.inlinequery.InlineQuery](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.inlinequery.InlineQuery) class is responsible for getting geolocation.

Here is the pseudo-code through which I *tried* to get geolocation in order to use latitude and longitude in the future:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

@client.on(events.InlineQuery)
async def handler(event):
    location = event.geo
    builder = event.builder

    await event.answer([
        builder.article("Coordinates: ", text="Long: " + location.long + "\nLat: " + location.lat),
    ])
```

But I can't do anything. Constantly outputs `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lat'`.

I would be grateful if you could help me in obtaining and **using** this data.

Comment: This is a bug. I've opened https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/3136 to track this issue.

Comment: @Lonami Thanks! I will wait for this bug to be fixed, since I really need to get geolocation. In fact, the entire work of my bot is based on this.

Comment: does this code have to be executed using only the telethon library or do you use another library as well?

Comment: @NematilloOchilov this all works only with the telethon. Getting geolocation is embedded in the telegram api itself, but for some reason telethon just performs a return, if you look at the link above from Lonami. As I understand, I just need to wait for the fix of this bug.

Comment: in pyrogram or pytelegrambotapi libraries I can quickly create what you are asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Telethon v1.23.0. The solution will be to update to a greater version (once that's out). In the meantime, you can still obtain the geo through the raw update:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

@client.on(events.InlineQuery)
async def handler(event):
    location = event.query.geo
    #                ^^^^^ raw update query
    builder = event.builder

    if location is None:
        # you still should check if the location is None because user may deny it or not have the GPS on
        return await event.answer([builder.article('Geo must be enabled!', text='Please enable GPS to use this bot'])

    await event.answer([
        builder.article("Coordinates: ", text="Long: " + location.long + "\nLat: " + location.lat),
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use your method until the update is released.